# expressionengine database class orderby and sort

Tags: expressionengine

How do we sort using the database class in expressionengine. `orderby` and `sort` are given an error and do not seem to work. I can't seem to find anything in the documantation about sorting results.  This is what i have.

```
$results = $this->EE->db->query("
    SELECT plan_name
    FROM exp__plans 
    WHERE member_id='1002' AND orderby="id" sort="desc" LIMIT 1
");
$x = $results->row('plan_name')
```

;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are issues with your query.

**try:**

```
$results = $this->EE->db->query("
    SELECT plan_name
    FROM exp_plans
    WHERE member_id = '1002' 
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 
");
```

I would recommend trying to run your query directly against the database if you're having trouble with it. 90% of the time it will be an issue with your SQL.

Also, you are writing this in a add-on... right? if you're trying to get this to work within a template I would recommend checking out the [query module](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/query/index.html).

Comment: Thank you. I got myself confused and used orderby and sort like i do in EE tags. All good now.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Active Record in order to create your query:

```
$this->EE->db->select('plan_name')
                ->from('plans')
                ->where('member_id', '1002')
                ->order_by("id", "desc")
                ->limit(1)
                ->get();
```

All the doc is on the [Codeigniter website](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html).

Comment: CI Active Record is great for queries like the above - but when it comes to more complicated tasks such as joins you'll quickly find yourself in a corner weeping.